# Having trouble tracking down Node JS memory leak

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, isomorphic-javascript

We're struggling with a memory leak problem on our first substantial Node/React Isomorphic web application.  In 48 hours or less we use over 500mb of memory. Most of what the application does is fetch json from a graphql server and use that data to make a web page composed from React components. There are a few other data sources used in the apps for special content but for the most part the meat and potatoes of the app  is graphql query to React components. Some of
the libraries we use to help include Express, NextJS, and Apollo Client.

On our servers we use a CDN to cache html pages for 60 seconds an we use Apache to proxy from port 443 (ssl) to the port we run node on.

Here is what we have attempted to do to resolve this leak:

- Use PM2 max-memory-restart parameter to force a restart before we run out of
  memory. This s a good band-aid but just a band-aid.
- Watched several videos on memory profiling including these:

  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L3ugr9BJqIs&t=416s
  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LaxbdIyBkL0
  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AeUCN2lPqL8
  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hliOMEQRqf8
- Done many rounds of memory profiling using Chrome's memory profiling tools and
  node --inspect. When we profile we typically run a local copy and use siege to
  hit a single route like the home page over and over for a minute like this:
  `siege -c12 -b --no-parser -t1m http://localhost:3000` . Then we run the same
  thing again a few more times  and take a memory heap snapshot. Having multiple
  heap snapshots allows us to use Chrome's memory comparison tools. When
  looking at the memory heap snapshots I never see any classes or functions we
  wrote in our application just a whole lot of objects, arrays and strings and
  such. There does seem to be quite a bit hanging around referring to https,
  socket connections, TLS Wrapper and Node Parser and HTTPParser.
- Tried refactoring to use persistent connections with node fetch and an HTTPS Agent
- Tried refactoring to lower the socket timeout so objects related to to graphql/https request could get garbage collected more easily .
- Tried refactoring to use memcached to prevent so many network connections forgraphql data.
- Ripped out the simplest route in the application (sitemap) and made it a stand alone application  that I could make several variations of to allow easy profiling and made it a stand alone application  that I could make several variations of to allow easy profiling. I also refactored this to try to make sure everything could get garage collected.  See it here: https://github.com/ghankerson/basic-node-http/blob/master/server.js see the memcache branch
  https://github.com/ghankerson/basic-node-http/blob/w-memcached/server.js  and
  the keep alive branch as well
  https://github.com/ghankerson/basic-node-http/blob/with--https-agent/server.js
  (Pardon the snarky variable names this has been trying).

Additional things I have tried:

- Stopped using Apollo Client's getDataFromTree which has been known to be slow  and in the past leak apparently https://spectrum.chat/next-js/general/next-js-with-apollo-memory-leak~503bb89f-0e59-4db6-accf-e336a9388f47.
- Ripped out gzipping from the application and let the Apache or CDN do it. This reduced memory heap size by about 2.5 to 3mb but did not prevent leaking.

Additional things we are doing soon:

- Stop serving static assets with Node and have Apache do it
- Perhaps put a reverse proxy between the Node app and the graphql server and have the TLS connection terminate there to remove the overhead needed for https.  Not sure this is worth it yet. Tried this on my laptop with Nginx but didn't see a lot of improvement -  not sure I got the https termination part right though.

So far I can only make these observations:

- I have spent a lot of time on this but have been unable to pinpoint the memory leak.
- I'm not sure my methodology is sound for detecting the leak.
- It looks like in the main application and in the contrived sitemap
  application and all the variations I've tried the basic memory profile
  doesn't change much.  It appears when running siege and profiling, that memory
  heap increases,  but eventually goes down a few minutes after requests stop.
  Still that is not something that happens on a site with steady traffic - there
  are requests coming in all the time. It seems like all the things in the heap
  used to make the network request to the graphql server just hand around too
  long. I'm just not sure this is the correct diagnosis  and if it is  what to do about it.

I can post memory heap snapshots if that helps.  Really hoping someone can point out where I am going wrong or at least provide a few good hints.

Initial feedback is get prod heap snapshots  so I  have some prod heap snapshots now interpreting them is the challenge as much as I read up on this its hard to interpret. This is all anonymous traffic so if you feel like looking at the snapshots here they are: [first one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/dalka3qunmi67s5/heapdump-1949401009.138076.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0), [second one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfythkz79orldpk/heapdump-1975689877.884835.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0), and [last one](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cmv1z0p20sycp78/heapdump-2021359748.688195.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0) they are zipped with bzip2 to cut download size. First one is right after a deploy so node restarted, next one is from that evening  and last is the next morning

[image: Comparison with previous snapshot]

This is a comparison of the last screenshot with previous one

[image: Summary view comparing with object allocated after the first snapshot]
Summary view comparing with object allocated after the first snapshot

What makes this hard is I don't see the code we wrote in there unless I drill way in

Comment: The usual starting point for node.js memory leaks is to take a server-side heapsnapshot before and then after you think it's leaked some, diff the two and see what types of objects are taking up the most space and use that as a n indicator of what code to go look at and study or what diagnostics to add.  Guessing and testing is a really hard way to find out what's going on.  You need some data to guide you.  And, this needs to be done server side.

Comment: Fair enough  I have some prod heap snapshots now  interpreting them  is the challenge as much as I read up on this  its hard to interpret.  
This is all anonymous traffic  so if you feel like looking at the snapshots  here they are:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/dalka3qunmi67s5/heapdump-1949401009.138076.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0, https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfythkz79orldpk/heapdump-1975689877.884835.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0,  https://www.dropbox.com/s/zfythkz79orldpk/heapdump-1975689877.884835.heapsnapshot.bz2?dl=0  they are zipped with bzip2  to cut download size.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in this case was to remove Express from the application. We were only using Express for routing and luckily NextJs implemented routing themselves around the same time.  The only other thing we did that helped was move an api call to NWS weather api call to be 100% client side.

After that the memory leak went away.